# Will POSIX sockets work between iOS Swift and Windows 10 C/C++?

Tags: ios, swift, windows, sockets, posix

DETAILS...
I want to run full duplex communication between a Swift client POSIX socket on iOS (iPhone) and a C/C++ server POSIX socket on Windows 10.

Windows 10 server is built with MinGW ("Minimalist GNU for Windows").

iOS client is built with Xcode.

Comment: Yes, sockets on iOS can communicate with sockets on Windows, and vice versa (and across any other platforms, for that matter).

Comment: Great.  Thanks, Remy.  That's what I'd believed.  There are multiple choices of socket wrappers on Windows and iOS and I'm struggling to decide which.